# Swift: Create mutable array with empty fields

Tags: ios, arrays, cocoa-touch, generics, swift

I want to create an array in Swift that is of type `UIImageView` but should initially  have some empty fields (`nil`) that act as placeholders. Is that possible? It was easy to create in Objective-C, like:

```
[self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]]
```

In Swift I define the array like this:

```
var pageViews:Array<UIImageView> = [];

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad();

    for i in 0 ..< 5
    {
        pageViews.append(nil);
    }
}
```

Of course that doesn't work. If I define the array with

```
var pageViews:Array<UIImageView!> = [];
```

I wont get a compile-time error but the app throws a fatal error:

**fatal error: attempt to bridge an implicitly unwrapped optional containing nil**

Is there any good workaround for this problem?

Comment: in this `Array<UIImageView!>`, what is the exclamation mark doing here exactly?

Comment: Defining the UIImageView as optional.

Comment: @holex: `UIImageView!` is an implicitly-unwrapped optional of `UIImageView`

Comment: This is not reproducible with the latest beta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to be able to store `nil` in the array, you have to define its type as storing an Optional value. You can also use the `count:repeatedValue:` initializer for convenience:

```
var pageViews = [UIImageView?](count: 5, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Comment: But implicitly-unwrapped optional can also store `nil`. The problem is with bridging.

Comment: @user102008 Yes because, as the error says, you cannot bridge an implicitly unwrapped optional containing `nil`. If he wants to bridge to Objective-C (which using UIImageView requires), he has to use a normal Optional.

Comment: @drewag: Of course you can bridge implicitly-unwrapped optionals. They get bridged to Objective-C object pointer type. `nil` gets bridged to `nil` pointer. It's just putting it in an `NSArray` that fails. Also, on the contrary, a normal Optional *cannot* be bridged to Objective-C. That's why your code worked -- by preventing the array from being bridged to `NSArray`.